# Maintain Focus for Input field in Pure Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

How to maintain focus for the input field even i clicked body the focus remains same for the input. Wherever i'm click focus remains same until I click next input filed. Last focused field must be in focus until i select next input field

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
}
button {
  border: 0;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 16px 'verdana', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" autofocus/>
 </p>
  <p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
 </p>
  <p>
   <input type="number" placeholder="Number" />
 </p>
 <p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Address" />
 </p>
 <p>
   <button>Submit</button>
 </p>
</form>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaovi/9zkfsLqe/8/)

Comment: This seems like bad practice, focus is for accessibility, why do you want to remove the users ability to change it? You would be preventing screen readers from leaving your form....

Comment: Include JavaScript that you have tried see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global variable which holds the current focused element. On every click you can check again if the target of click was a new input then update the current focused element else force focus on previous focused input:

```js
var $currentFocus;

$(document).on("click",function(event){
    $currentElement=$(":focus");
    if ($(event.target).is("input")) {
        $currentFocus=$(event.target);
        return; 
    }
    else{
       $currentFocus.focus();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
 </p>
  <p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
 </p>
  <p>
   <input type="number" placeholder="Number" />
 </p>
 <p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Address"/>
 </p>
 <p>
   <button>Submit</button>
 </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can i get in Pure Js instead of jQurey

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable like an enum to hold the information of the current field being focus.

You would also add in all of the fields you mentioned an `onblur` event listener so that, whenever a field lost focus, a function would be called.

On that function you could check if the new element on focus is one of the fields you want and if not, return focus to the previous field.

For that you could add ids to the fields and use `document.activeElement` to know which is the new element being focused.

I haven't tested it but I believe it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS

```js
    var focusedAt = "";
    
    function focused(field) {
     focusedAt = field;
    }
    
    function blurred(field) {
     if (focusedAt === "")
           document.getElementById(field).focus();
    }
    
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
     console.log(e);
      if (e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT")
          focusedAt = ""
    }, true);
```

```html
    <form>
     <p>
       <input id="fname" onfocus="focused('fname')" onblur="blurred('fname')" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
     </p>
      <p>
       <input id="lname" onfocus="focused('lname')" onblur="blurred('lname')" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
     </p>
      <p>
       <input id="number" onfocus="focused('number')" onblur="blurred('number')" type="number" placeholder="Number" />
     </p>
     <p>
       <input id="address" onfocus="focused('address')" onblur="blurred('address')" type="text" placeholder="Address" />
     </p>
     <p>
       <button>Submit</button>
     </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: This would be so much cleaner if you have jQ